# Deny access to a specific folder for a sudo user

Tags: bash, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I have a question: I am root in an Ubuntu system. I want to give a user (say username is X) permission to execute any command but at the same time I have a folder that I want no one to be able to access except my user (which is certainly not X because it is say Admin) or root. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You might get somewhere with selinux or encryption; ordinary unix permission models won't accommodate this desire.

Comment: Any chance restricting the list of commands user can run?

Comment: @A2B If you just blacklist some executables he could compile his own. If no compiler is on that box he can compile on another system with the same architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a user can execute any commands as `sudo` he can also become `root` whenever he wants. That's why there is not a chance to protect a directory from browsing by such a user unless you restrict the list of commands the user can execute with `sudo`.

One idea could be to put the folder on a separate partition which is encrypted with a password. The user would need to decrypt the partition before he could mount that folder.

Comment: So, the closest I got to an answer was to deny permission and don't let user run chmod and chown. But user can easily be smart and do it with 10 other ways. Any suggestions?

Comment: hmm, interesting. I expected this to be the last option. It seems it has come to that! Thanks! Will wait a bit for other opinions and if no one has better solution will accept yours :)

Comment: You may find tools [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27770/is-there-a-tool-to-encrypt-a-file-or-directory). However all that tools deal with encryption.

Comment: @A2B You've suggested an edit, where you mentioned SELinux features could be used. The edit was rejected by *community*, not by me. I'm basically open for a SEL based solution, however we should be more specific instead of just mentioning it. Do you have a certain SEL based solution in mind? If yes, then let's create an example.